# Flutter wont build on my machine but builds on others err:...\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the below error whenever I try to build my app. There are numerous variations of this problem on S.O. and on Github but none of the solutions have worked in my case. I have:
a. Upgraded Gradle
b. removed read-only recursively (from root folder).
c. Deleted and reinstalled SDK
d. Flutter pub upgrade
e. Flutter clean
and more...

:Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             28.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

flutter run -v:

```
[  +81 ms] [  +23 ms] Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path =
'D:\FLUTTER_APPS\avocat_2.1\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\*' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
[   +3 ms]            , errno = 3)
[        ]            #0      _Directory._fillWithDirectoryListing (dart:io-patch/directory_patch.dart:37:68)
[   +1 ms]            #1      _Directory.listSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:243:5)
[   +1 ms]            #2      ForwardingDirectory.listSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_directory.dart:43:12)    
[   +3 ms]            #3      ForwardingDirectory.listSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_directory.dart:43:12)    
[   +1 ms]            #4      _AssetDirectoryCache.variantsFor (package:flutter_tools/src/asset.dart:946:78)
[   +1 ms]            #5      ManifestAssetBundle._parseAssetFromFile (package:flutter_tools/src/asset.dart:786:37)
[   +1 ms]            #6      ManifestAssetBundle._parseAssets (package:flutter_tools/src/asset.dart:691:9)
[   +2 ms]            #7      ManifestAssetBundle.build (package:flutter_tools/src/asset.dart:246:53)
[   +3 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +6 ms]            #8      copyAssets (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/assets.dart:53:26)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #9      AndroidAssetBundle.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/android.dart:65:34)  
[   +6 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +3 ms]            #10     _BuildInstance._invokeInternal
(package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:836:9)
[   +7 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +6 ms]            #11     FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:603:16)    
[   +7 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +3 ms]            #12     AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:314:32)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #13     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[  +10 ms]            #14     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)       
[   +8 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[  +14 ms]            #15     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +9 ms]            #16     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #17     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)       
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #18     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +6 ms]            #19     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +3 ms]            #20     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)       
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #21     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
[   +5 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms] [  +10 ms] 
[   +1 ms]            #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
[   +1 ms]            #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:331:7)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)       
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +4 ms]            #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
[   +3 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)       
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +5 ms]            #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms]            #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms] [  +36 ms] "flutter assemble" took 3,243ms.
[ +104 ms] [ +264 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 262ms
[   +1 ms] [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] [   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
[ +104 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[ +496 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[  +13 ms] * Where:
[   +1 ms] Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[   +1 ms] > Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[  +46 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
[  +16 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[  +52 ms] BUILD FAILED in 15s
[   +1 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[  +16 ms] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[   +1 ms] 67 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 63 up-to-date
[ +517 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 16.5s)
[+10554 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +2 ms] "flutter run" took 31,325ms.
[   +4 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:669:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)   
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)     
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1415], locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at D:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (9 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\corpo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\corpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM G973U (mobile) • 192.168.0.141:5555 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome             • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
    • Edge (web)        • edge               • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.68

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this issue as well. Deleting both `./build` directory and `./android/app/build` fixed the issue for me.

Update:

The error returns after building the app a few times. This issue occurred after I added the android_intent_plus package. This package also causes the javascript channels in webview_flutter to not work in release mode.

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/630

Here's the workaround as mentioned here https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/282:

file: `android/build.gradle`

```
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

Changed to:

```
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}   
subprojects {   
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

Comment: I tried all that but none worked. Even after deleting the ENTIRE local folder and cloning the repo from GitHub, it builds as long as I make no changes. But the moment just SAVE, it never builds anymore.